# Assembly signing - Xamarin pcl and UWP app

Tags: xamarin, signing, assembly-signing

I am signing both pcl and uwp and getting error:

```
 System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
```

Indeed the assembly Xamarin.Forms.Xaml is not signed (Strong name = false)

Comment: Assembly Linking will destroy any strong naming and App signing will "protect" against assembly tampering, so strong naming does not make sense for UWP/Xamarin.Android and on iOS published apps are required to be AOT'd (again voiding any initial assembly signing).

Comment: So you suggest to just remove the app signing?

Comment: In a signed self-enclosed app, I do not see the point of it. Strong names make sense for GAC-based assembles, classic desktop/server deployments, etc... but with a signed Android/iOS/UWP app you can not alter the contents without re-signing it.